# Bot not Responding Alert in Google Chat API

Tags: google-hangouts, google-chat

I have used same code as mentioned in one of the samples available on Google Chat Documentation
https://github.com/googleworkspace/hangouts-chat-samples/blob/master/java/basic-async-bot/src/main/java/com/google/chat/bot/basic/async/Bot.java

But the google chat is first giving the message "BOTNAME not responding" then the reply from the bot.
I have even tried to post the message with the thread from previous message as mentioned in the documentation. But still not getting desired result.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: I am even sending http 204 status code i.e request accepted when the request first comes.

Comment: All the responses from bot is working fine. But I don't want to have "Bot not responding message" every time, even when bot responds to the message correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got it. Actually, I was sending a response to google chat with some content. When I modified it, by sending a response without any content, the error is resolved and it is working fine as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

it's a shame I didn't see this issue before.

Check your APPSCRIPT.JSON for a chat property {} at the end. With updates when deploying is being overwritten but Google is already solving =)

Ex of my appssript.json: (Correct)

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Fortaleza",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "cGoa",
        "libraryId": "1v_l4xN3ICa0lAW315NQEzAHPSoNiFdWHsMEwj2qA5t9cgZ5VWci2Qxv2",
        "version": "36"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "OAuth1",
        "libraryId": "1CXDCY5sqT9ph64fFwSzVtXnbjpSfWdRymafDrtIZ7Z_hwysTY7IIhi7s",
        "version": "18"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "Verificacao_CallBack",
        "libraryId": "1dgfE9K71u1k7tkxQHy2F2oAAAYB_lVnZOj8bmL0sl-vMEQYq8bYrDE1J",
        "version": "0",
        "developmentMode": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "chat": {
  }
}
```

You can deploys news versions in OLD apps script editors!